# how to set a view's background color using a precise hex via interfacebuilder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

In IB, when I go to the attributes inspector and click the "background" drop down -> other, I get a color pallet with several tabs (wheel, slider, apllets) but there is no place to set a precise such as #ff5911 for example.

Is there a way to do that without using code?

Comment: You can select the updated answer for Xcode 6 ( by @rizzes ), as it's now possible to use hex code in interface builder, directly. Just that, future viewer of the post can see it directly. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hex color picker to your system. I use http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is much needed. here are the installation instructions for whoever is interested: http://yuji.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/mac-adding-hex-color-picker-to-color-picker/

Answer (score 15):

In Xcode 6, you can set hex values in the RGB slider tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for updating for Xcode 6. This helped me. +1

Comment: These however show up differently in the app due to color profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to the RGB-Slider and use the RGB value of your hex code. There are several converters in the web:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

```
ff5911 => R: 255, G: 89, B: 17
```

I think there isn't the possibility in the Interace Builder to directly put in the hex value. Another way would be using the "magnifier" symbol and click on the desired color.